# how to set an image as background in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, background

I was able to add the background only to the fields that were added in the screen with the below code:
`VerticalFieldManager manager = new VerticalFieldManager();`

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Penguins.jpg");

    Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(image);
    manager.setBackground(bg);
    manager.add(new LabelField("HEll"));
    add(manager);</code>
```

the output screen is like below:[image]

How will get the image filled with whole screen, with the fields visible on top of it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap background = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png");

VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                g.drawBitmap(0, 0, "Device Width", "Device Height",
                                background, 0, 0);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };

vfm.add(new LabelField("HEll"));
add(vfm);
```

Comment: Thank you. it is working. But is there any way to set the background without using field manager? and also how to lock the screen from scrolling?

Comment: If you want to lock Vertical Scroll then use
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);

for Horizontal 
  
HorizontalFieldManager hManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this code to set the background image in Blackberry, But this works only 5.0 or above.

```
Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap bitmap);

// OR

Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap bitmap, int positionX, int positionY, int repeat);

this.getMainManager().setBackground(bg);
```

Comment: hi @Neel its working but when Mainscreen have lots of content ..than background image also scroll with it ..that times it looks so blury ... what is the solution for that?

Comment: which one u have tried the first one or the 2nd option for Creating  background  object?